# Windows Service installation requirements

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have VS project(service), and on my machine I install it using installutil.exe. Now I need to install on a random windows machine. I'm not familiar with Windows, what dependencies should this machine meet?

Comment: corresponding version of the .Net on target maching should be enough (in order to call installutil.exe ).

Comment: @Vladimir what about architecture?

Comment: what do you mean by architecture ? Can you please explain ?